# adb shell commands for Qualcomm chipset

Tags: android, shell, wifi, adb, chipset

Good Day everyone, here i am looking for some suggestions about android `adb shell` commands about `Qualcomm` wifi chipset. I learned that for `Broadcom` , in `adb shell` we can find chipset version by "`wl ver`" , for country "`wl country`" and "wl channels" for supported channel lists. `wl` is a open tool so far i know.

Now i wonder, if there is any command for `Qualcomm`. Thanks for your valuable suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found "iw", a tool that works for devices with the Qualcomm chipset.

Answer (score -1):

For Qualcomm Chip you can use **iw** and **iwpriv** commands. It works.